# Pourquoi pas « Tu as des bons amis » ?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants, de

Pourquoi dans une forme plurielle telle que « Tu as de bons amis » emploie-t-on « de » plutôt que « des »?

Est-ce que c'est incorrect si on dit « Tu as des bons amis » ?

Comment: @Laure J'ai effacé ma réponse parce que j'ai vu que c'était downvotée. Est-ce que tu peux comprendre les votes négatifs ? Est-ce fautive et pourquoi ? Merci encore !

Comment: @Dimitris Je n'ai ↓ aucune des réponses sur cette page. Se mettre dans la tête de ceux qui l'ont fait n'est pas facile. Peut-être parce que tu as dit que c'est une faute ?  Ce n'est pas une faute, c'est plus une question d'usage, **en principe** on met *de* (sans l'article défini donc) si le nom est pris dans un sens indéfini. La réponse *duplicate* explique ça. Ou alors parce que tu n'as pas répondu à la question « pourquoi » (c.a.d donner l'explication et pas la règle, mais dans ce cas l'autre réponse sur cette page aurait dû aussi être ↓.

Answer (score 1):

Normalement, on applique la règle trouvée [ici](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/049.html).

Quand l’article indéfini pluriel (pas singulier (un, une), ni massif (de la, du)) détermine un groupe nominal contenant un ad­jectif antéposé (qui précède le nom), il prend la forme « de ». Comparer :

- Il m’a offert des fleurs magnifiques (*adjectif postposé*)
- Il m’a offert de belles fleurs. (*adjectif antéposé*)
- Je vous donne un autre exemple. → Je vous donne d’autres exemples.
- Ils ont acheté un grand poster. → Ils ont acheté de grands posters.

La règle s’applique aussi quand l’adjectif est modifié par divers adverbes, qui viennent se placer entre celui-ci et le déterminant.

- Il a dit de **si** belles choses.
- Ce sont de **très** bons exemples.
- Elle a d’**assez** bons résultats scolaires.

Dans ce cas, le mot « de » est simplement une forme que l’article indéfini prend dans un cas particulier. Ce n’est pas une préposition.

Il faut bien faire attention aux exclusions qui sont formulées dans la règle.

1. La transformation de l’article indéfini en « de » ne concerne que la forme comptable du pluriel de l’ar­ticle indéfini.
2. Au singulier et au massif, il n’y a pas de transformation devant adjectif antéposé.

   - une grande mai­son, du bon vin.

Il existe deux cas qui font exception à la règle.

— Cas des mots composés (une seule unité sémantique).

- un petit pois → des petits pois
- un jeune homme  → des jeunes hommes
- une jeune fille→ des jeunes filles
- une petite cuillère  → des petites cuillères
- un petit four  → des petits fours
- une grande personne  → des grandes personnes
- une bonnes amie → des bonnes amies

— Cas de la langue parlée

La règle n'est souvent pas appliquée dans la langue parlée.

Donc, vous pourriez dire « Tu as des bons amis. » si vous parlez à quelqu'un, mais « Tu as de bon amis. » est toujours préférable, à mon avis.